# How might I fix this bug in the cheat command's tab completion zsh script?

Tags: autocomplete, zsh

There is a bug report in the open source cheat project described here: https://github.com/cheat/cheat/issues/632

As described in that bug report, a variable named `$state` never gets set. Looking at the code, it should be set to a value of "none", "full", "personal", "taglist", or "pathlist".

The completion script is here: https://github.com/cheat/cheat/blob/master/scripts/cheat.zsh

I don't know if this script is unfinished or what. But not being a very good shell scripting and knowing nothing about zsh completion, I don't have any ideas on how I might set the `$state` variable to the appropriate value.

If someone can offer suggestions, I'd appreciate it.

**UPDATE**
I'm using ohmyzsh, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I just made the default value for `state` to be 'full'. Seems to work.

```
_cheat() {
  local state
  state='full'

...snip...
```

Then it get overridden by the `_arguments` portion of the code.